# Run a batch file for Windows SAS 9.1

Tags: windows, batch-file, sas

I'm using SAS 9.1 on Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition. I'm trying to run two programs in a batch mode. My .bat file contains exactly two rows:

```
Start "D:\PROGRAM FILES\SAS\SAS 9.1" -SYSIN "C:\MyFolder\prog1.sas"
Start "D:\PROGRAM FILES\SAS\SAS 9.1" -SYSIN "C:\MyFolder\prog2.sas"
```

After I double-click on the .bat file icon, the following message appears: "Windows cannot find 'SYSIN'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again. To search for a file, click the Start button, and then click Search".
How could this be fixed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have your SAS executable be part of the line - not just the folder (and that's likely not the right folder, though I don't recall the 9.1 folder structure - and please, please upgrade from 9.1, that's over a decade old).

Since you don't include anything with a .exe (or .com/etc.) extension, Windows probably is assuming the folder you put there is supposed to be the "Title" argument to the `START` command.

Include the full path to SAS.EXE including SAS.EXE itself, and see if that does what you need.  If not, try removing START as that may be confusing things.

See [Batch Processing Under Windows](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Batch_processing_under_Windows) and the first listing under [Four ways to schedule SAS tasks](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2013/08/14/four-ways-to-schedule-sas-tasks/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Removing leading "Start " and adding ".exe" to the command is sufficient:

```
"D:\PROGRAM FILES\SAS\SAS 9.1\sas.exe" -SYSIN "C:\MyFolder\prog1.sas"
"D:\PROGRAM FILES\SAS\SAS 9.1\sas.exe" -SYSIN "C:\MyFolder\prog2.sas"
```

(Thanks to all who answered here and to KurtBremser from the SAS Community.)

Comment: You also added sas.exe to the call.  Unless the original question contained a typo.

Comment: Using the START command will also let them run in parallel.  Now only one SAS program will run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the two programs to run in parallel since you are using `START`? You need to add a title as the second argument, just insert "SAS" after `START` like this:

```
Start "SAS" "D:\PROGRAM FILES\SAS\SAS 9.1" -SYSIN "C:\MyFolder\prog1.sas"
Start "SAS" "D:\PROGRAM FILES\SAS\SAS 9.1" -SYSIN "C:\MyFolder\prog2.sas"
```

Ah, looking at Joe's answer, you probably need to add sas.exe to the command as well.